# How to add layers to a sequential model from an existing model?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras

I am using VGG16 as my base CNN model:

```
base_model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(64,64,3) )
```

I want to create a new model and add the layers of VGG16 to my model one by one before adding my own layers.

I know how to add news layers manually using model.add() command, but I am not sure how can I loop over my base model layers and add them to my model

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question.

```
bn = []
for layer in base_model.layers:
    bn.append(layer)
model = Sequential(bn)
model.summary()
```